# How do create a step chart in Pandas with time series data from two seperate data sources

Tags: python, pandas

I have two time-series datasets that I want to make a step-chart of.

The time series data is between Monday 2015-04-20 and Friday 2015-04-24.

The first dataset contains 26337 rows with values ranging from 0-1.
The second dataset contains 80 rows with values between 0-4.

First dataset represents motion sensor values in a room, with around 2-3 minutes between each measurement. 1 indicates the room is occupied, 0 indicates that it is empty. The second contains data from a survey where users could fill in how many people were in the same room, at the time they were answering the survey.

Now I want to compare this data, to find out how well the sensor performs. Obviously there is a lot of data that is "missing" in the second set. Is there a way to fill in the "blanks" in a step chart?

Each row has the following format:
Header
Timestamp (%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S),value

Example: 
Time,Occupancy
24-04-2015 21:40:33,1
24-04-2015 21:43:11,0

.....

So far I have managed to import the first dataset and make a plot of it. Unfortunately the x-axis is not showing dates, but a lot of numbers:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime

data = open('PIRDATA.csv')
ts = pd.Series.from_csv(data, sep=',')

plot(ts);
```

Result:
[image]

How would I go on from here on now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Pandas to read the data, using the Date column as the index (parsing the values to dates).

```
data = pd.read_csv('PIRDATA.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=0)
```

To achieve your step chart objective, try:

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter 
from matplotlib.dates import HourLocator 


small_dataset = pd.read_csv('SURVEY_RESULTS_WEEK1.csv', header=0,index_col=0, parse_dates=0) 
big_dataset = pd.read_csv('PIRDATA_RAW_CONVERTED_DATETIME.csv', header=0,index_col=0, parse_dates=0) 

small_dataset.rename(columns={'Occupancy': 'Survey'}, inplace=True) 
big_dataset.rename(columns={'Occupancy': 'PIR'}, inplace=True) 

big = big_dataset.plot() 
big.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%y-%m-%d H: %H')) 
big.xaxis.set_major_locator(HourLocator(np.arange(0, 25, 6))) 
big.set_ylabel('Occupancy') 

small_dataset.plot(ax=big, drawstyle='steps') 

fig = plt.gcf() 
fig.suptitle('PIR and Survey Occupancy Comparsion') 

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Pandas doesn't know how to parse the dates. Here is the exception: http://pastebin.com/6Ln0nkay

Comment: pd.read_csv works fine for me per above.  Your exception stack indicates you used this function instead: df = pd.Series.from_csv(data, sep=',', index_col=0)

Comment: Yes it's true. pd.Series.from_csv caused the exception. However, what do you suggest doing after I have loaded the CSV file? I need to plot the data somehow.

Comment: I can read the data.  But I cant plot it. I added a method to parse the string to a datetime object. Please have a look at this: http://pastebin.com/T7jCsaLK - I have uploaded a sample of the data that I am parsing as well: http://pastebin.com/mufv5Wyx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78124/discussion-between-kenci-and-alexander).